# Selenium iterating through unordered list but not getting the right text

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am writing a craigslist search bot using selenium, and I am trying to iterate through search results which are in an unordered list. It is iterating but not getting the link text that I want. Anybody have any ideas?

```py
browser.get('https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/sfv/sss?')

searchForm = browser.find_element_by_id("query")
searchForm.click()

searchForm.send_keys(whatWant)
sendClick = browser.find_element_by_class_name("searchbtn")
sendClick.click()

ulSelector = browser.find_element_by_class_name("rows")
liClass = ulSelector.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for links in liClass:
    print(links.get_attribute('href'))
```

and I am getting as output

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
[many more Nones - truncated]
```

I know it's iterating but not getting the right text.

Answer (score 0):

```
for links in liClass:
    print(links.find_element_by_xpath('./a').get_attribute('href'))
```

Get the a tag and not the li tag to grab the ahref values from.

Comment: Thank you so much Arundeep!